# Tropical Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c#, c++

What changes to following code can make it work to multiply matrices tropically (Tropical Algebra).

Tropical Algebra is:
x ⊕ y = minimum of x and y
x ⊗ y = x + y

```
  for(i=0;i<m;++i)
  {
   for(j=0;j<q;++j)
   {
    c[i][j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<n;++k)      

     c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][k]*b[k][j]);       

     cout<<c[i][j]<<" ";
   }
   cout<<"\n";
  }
```

I am also developing it in C#. would be much help full if there is built in libraries for this in C#.

Comment: You do not explain well enough what you mean by tropical algebra. Besides, what does the dot product mean, in particular what kind of addition used in the dot product?

Comment: @user1978011: I guess he means [max-plus algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra)?

Comment: yes its max-plus algebra. where when we add two numbers we take least of them as result and when we multiply two we actually add them.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47359743/6338725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matrix multiplication you aim for is indeed  `c_ij = a_i1 ⊗ b_1j ⊕...⊕ a_in ⊗ b_nj`, your code should be

```
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
   for (j = 0; j < q; ++j) {
      auto tmp = (a[i][0] + b[0][j]); // this is the first ⊗
      for (k = 1; k < n; ++k)
         // std::min is the ⊕ operation
         tmp = std::min(tmp, (a[i][k] + b[k][j]));

      c[i][j] = tmp;
      cout << c[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << "\n";
}
```

If you don't use c++11, you have to substitute `auto` by the type of the elements in your matrix.