# How to make Min-plus matrix multiplication in python faster?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

So I have two matrices, A and B, and I want to compute the min-plus product as given here: [Min-plus matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication). For that I've implemented the following:

```
def min_plus_product(A,B):
    B = np.transpose(B)
    Y = np.zeros((len(B),len(A)))
    for i in range(len(B)):
         Y[i] = (A + B[i]).min(1)
    return np.transpose(Y)
```

This works fine, but is slow for big matrices, is there a way to make it faster? I've heard that implemeting in C or using the GPU might be good options.

Comment: How big are your inputs? How does the speed of your `min_plus_product` compare to the speed of an ordinary matrix multiplication with `dot`?

Comment: *"...slow for big matrices"*  Same question as @user2357112: what is a typical size of your matrices?

Comment: I tested with A 10000 by 100 and B 100 by 20000 and got 135s for mine, 1.95s for np.dot. My matrices can be even bigger than this sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an algo that saves a bit if the middle dimension is large enough and entries are uniformly distributed. It exploits the fact that the smallest sum typically will be from two small terms.

```
import numpy as np

def min_plus_product(A,B):
    B = np.transpose(B)
    Y = np.zeros((len(B),len(A)))
    for i in range(len(B)):
         Y[i] = (A + B[i]).min(1)
    return np.transpose(Y)


def min_plus_product_opt(A,B, chop=None):
    if chop is None:
        # not sure this is optimal
        chop = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(A.shape[1])))
    B = np.transpose(B)
    Amin = A.min(1)
    Y = np.zeros((len(B),len(A)))
    for i in range(len(B)):
        o = np.argsort(B[i])
        Y[i] = (A[:, o[:chop]] + B[i, o[:chop]]).min(1)
        if chop < len(o):
            idx = np.where(Amin + B[i, o[chop]] < Y[i])[0]
            for j in range(chop, len(o), chop):
                if len(idx) == 0:
                    break
                x, y = np.ix_(idx, o[j : j + chop])
                slmin = (A[x, y] + B[i, o[j : j + chop]]).min(1)
                slmin = np.minimum(Y[i, idx], slmin)
                Y[i, idx] = slmin
                nidx = np.where(Amin[idx] + B[i, o[j + chop]] < Y[i, idx])[0]
                idx = idx[nidx]
    return np.transpose(Y)

A = np.random.random(size=(1000,1000))
B = np.random.random(size=(1000,2000))

print(np.allclose(min_plus_product(A,B), min_plus_product_opt(A,B)))

import time
t = time.time();min_plus_product(A,B);print('naive {}sec'.format(time.time()-t))
t = time.time();min_plus_product_opt(A,B);print('opt {}sec'.format(time.time()-t))
```

Sample output:

```
True
naive 7.794037580490112sec
opt 1.65810227394104sec
```

Comment: @Rael Thanks for the accept. Just a remark in case you are still thinking of going to C (I recommend Cython, in my experience it interfaces painlessly with numpy and is more mature than its version number might suggest) In that case the code can be heavily simplified. Basically you don't need to chunk and also not to mask and reindex, instead you just loop over the rows of `a` and do the short-circuiting for each row in one go.

Answer (score 1):

A possible simple route is to use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org).

```py
from numba import autojit
import numpy as np
@autojit(nopython=True)
def min_plus_product(A,B):
    n = A.shape[0]
    C = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            minimum = A[i,0]+B[0,j]
            for k in range(1,n):
                minimum = min(A[i,k]+B[k,j],minimum)
            C[i,j] = minimum
    return C
```

Timings on 1000x1000 A,B matrices are:

1 loops, best of 3: 4.28 s per loop for the original code

1 loops, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop for the numba code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a succinct and fully numpy solution, without any python-based loops:

```
(np.expand_dims(a, 0) + np.expand_dims(b.T, 1)).min(axis=2).T
```

Comment: You are a genius. Just figured out this takes advantage of [broadcasting](https://towardsdatascience.com/broadcasting-in-numpy-58856f926d73).